# How AspNet Identity with my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to go through this tutorial on [the External Authentication Services (C#)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on). I need some initial explanations to go forward. Looking inside the default template that ships MVC5, I see this:

```
// You can add profile data for the user ...
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string HomeTown { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

What if I want to call it **User** instead of **ApplicationUser**? Maybe I want to add a navigation properties so I can establish relationship with my other models? Also when I look at the table, the name is **AspNetUsers** instead of **ApplicationUser**. Finally, What if I want to use my own context?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> 1)What if I want to call it User instead of ApplicationUser?

You can change to any names you want, just make sure to replace ApplicationUser with the name.

> 2)Maybe I want to add a navigation properties so I can establish
>   relationship with my other models?

If you have a class call Address, you want to add addressId as a foreign key, see below:

```
 public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string HomeTown { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

> 3)Also when I look at the table, the name is AspNetUsers instead of
>   ApplicationUser.

ASP.NET Identity is inherited from the The ASP.NET membership system. When you register a new user
using the default template, AspNetUsers and AspNetUserRoles etc.. these tables are created by default.
You can modify these table name by modifying the IdentityModel.cs. For more detail take a look at the following link:

[How can I change the table names when using Visual Studio 2013 ASP.NET Identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460386/how-can-i-change-the-table-names-when-using-visual-studio-2013-aspnet-identity)

> 4)What if I want to use my own context?

You can create your own DBContex, MVC 5 allow you to have mutiple DBContext, such as ApplicationDbContext and DataDbContext(custom DbContext).
ApplicationDbContext usually contains ASP.NET Membership data table.
DataDbContext usually contains data tables unrelated to users.

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public int Title { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() 
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

Note: You may need to use EF Migrations, see details here :

[ASP.Net Identity customizing UserProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814432/asp-net-identity-customizing-userprofile/19822728#19822728)

Comment: Where the default DB and tables are created?

Comment: @Lin, Thanks a lot for this answer. another quick question - what if I want to have a field in my own model to reference the ApplicationUser. How do I accomplish this?