# MVC 5 : Asp.net Identity : How to model UserRole

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am new to MVC 5 asp.net Identity model and was looking for means to customise standard Asp.net Identity to suit my needs. Through blog on [TypeCast Exception](http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx#Adding-the-UserRoles-Method-to-the-AccountController) and one at [Stackoverflow: How to model Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979947/how-aspnet-identity-with-my-model) I was able to create my own elements in ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole tables. However, my requirement is to add new columns to UserRole table, DATE_FROM and DATE_TO which I did by implementing `IdentityUserRole` interface. My problem is when I'm trying to save the link UserManager.AddRoleToUser takes only two parameters, UserName and RoleName. How to store parameters for custom `ApplicationUserRole` ?

```
public bool AddUserToRole(string userId, SelectUserRolesViewModel roleName)
{
                var um = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
                    new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));


                var idResult = um.AddToRole(userId, roleName);
                return idResult.Succeeded;
            }
```

the SelectUserRolesViewModel supplies extended IdnetityUserRole model. Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, I have successfully added new attributes to IdentityUser and IdentityRole. Now my requirement is to assign roles to users which are valid only between DATE_FROM and DATE_TO. For this, i have extended `IdentityUserRole` interface to include these fields. However I'm not able to save them as UserManager.AddToRole does not accept custom class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add additional properties to the ApplicationUserRole table, you can't use `AddUserToRole` method anymore. Because `AddUserToRole` method is from `UserManagerExtensions` class which is sealed class, you cann't create your own class to inherit from `UserManagerExtensions`. I'm not sure there are any better solution for this, but below is a working example.

Add additional properties to the  `ApplicationUserRole` table:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole
{
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create a new `ApplicationUserRole` instance like below:

```
    using (var _db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var roleName = //Get role name from somewhere here
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(_db));
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
        {
             var newRoleresult = roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole()
             {
                  Name = roleName,
             });
        }
        var userRole = new ApplicationUserRole
        {
            UserId = currentUser.Id,
            RoleId = roleManager.FindByName(roleName).Id,
            DateFrom = DateTime.Now,
            DateTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
        };
        _db.ApplicationUserRoles.Add(userRole);
        _db.SaveChanges();
   }
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you are creating attributes for IdentityRole table. What I wanted is to assign a Role to User which is valid between DATE_FROM and DATE_TO. for this purpose I added two attributes to ApplicationUserRole (extending IdentityUserRole interface)

Comment: hi @siddhant4u, sorry I misunderstood your question. I updated my answer, take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed my issue. Now I can design my custom security around your work :)